# putting a text and image side by side with aligning the text to the top

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get an image and text  to sit side by side  with the image on the  right and the text on the left, text to align at the top 
but it keeps align at  the bottom

this  is my code

```css
 box{
display: inline-block;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
        <p>
            <img class="map" src="map.png" alt="Home delivery area" />

            </p>

    </div>

    <div class="box">
    Text text Text textText textText textText textText textText text <br />
    Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text.<br>
    Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text<br />
    Text textText textText textText text. <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
    <br />
    Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text <br />
    Text textText textText textText textText text

    </p>
        </div>
```

ANY suggestions  what I'm doing wrong

Comment: i cant use float

Comment: you have not applied dot(.) in the css selector for the box class use .box instead of box first

Comment: text is still  align to the bottom  of the image

Answer (score 0):

place the text first and then the image like this

the css

```
.box{
display: inline-block;
width:auto;
height:auto;
margin: 10px;

}
```

the html

`

```
<div class="box">
Text text Text textText textText textText textText textText text <br />
Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text.<br>
Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text<br />
Text textText textText textText text. <br />
<br />
<br />
Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
<br />
Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text <br />
Text textText textText textText textText text

</p>
    </div>



    <div class="box">
    <p>
        <img class="map" src="map.png" alt="Home delivery area" />

        </p>

</div>
```

`

Comment: and every  time  i use  float  it stuffs up

Comment: in my code by just placing image div to bottom its working

Comment: i also have to check that

Answer (score 0):

Use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and change the direction to row-reverse. You can put all of the content inside one element class.

```css
.box{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
   <img class="map" src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="Home delivery area" />

    Text text Text textText textText textText textText textText text <br />
    Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text.<br>
    Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text<br />
    Text textText textText textText text. <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
    <br />
    Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text <br />
    Text textText textText textText textText text


    </div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qsfLw2ms/2/)

Comment: that  has stretched  the image and the  text , but at least its  side by side  now

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you didn't want to use float, but it could be vary useful. Especially if you put the p and the img in the same .box

```css
.box img{
  float:right;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
   <img class="map" src="http://fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="Home delivery area" /> 
   <p>
    
    Text text Text textText textText textText textText textText text <br />
    Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text.<br>
    Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text<br />
    Text textText textText textText text. <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
    <br />
    Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text 
    Text textText textText textText textText text
     Text text Text textText textText textText textText textText text <br />
    Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text.<br>
    Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text<br />
    Text textText textText textText text. <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
    <br />
    Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text 
    Text textText textText textText textText text
        Text textText textText textText text. <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
    <br />
    Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text 
    Text textText textText textText textText text

    </p>
        </div>
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use float

Comment: Do you need the text to be able to go side by side the image only, not under it if the text is too large?

Comment: Are you allowed to put the image after the paragraph or does it have to be before? Or better yet, what are the exact instructions for this assignment?

Comment: i can't  invite  you to a chat but you may  be able  to invite  me to a chat i can show  you my  desktop by team viewer

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single container and `display:table` properties to keep both text  image side by side **at any time**.

`p` displayed as `table-cell` will accept `vertical-align` to lay content at top , middle or bottom.

Finally, `direction` can be used to reorder the layout

```css
.box {
  display: table;
  direction: rtl;/* lay ps from right to left , mind a reset to the children for the text  inline contents */
  border-spacing: 10px;/* instead the margin */
}

p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  direction: initial;/* back to your document direction */
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>
    <img class="map" src="map.png" alt="Home delivery area" />
  </p>
  <p>
    Text text Text textText textText textText textText textText text <br /> Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text.<br> Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text<br /> Text textText textText
    textText text. <br />
    <br />
    <br /> Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
    <br /> Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text <br /> Text textText textText textText textText text

  </p>
</div>
```